# Why does [1..5] in Rascal return [1,2,3,4]?

Tags: rascal

I expect it to return [1,2,3,4,5] as in Haskell.

Comment: The manual says it should be inclusive: http://www.meta-environment.org/doc/books/analysis/rascal-manual/rascal-manual.html#id1142539 http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Range/Range.html

Comment: thanks! the manual is out of date. Will fix.

Comment: manual was fixed in the meantime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: the left index is inclusive and the right is exclusive by design.

Long answer: the reason for the short answer is that lists are zero indexed, and we noticed everybody having to write (or forgetting to write) `[0..size(myList) - 1]`. Now we can write `[0..size(myList)]` instead. It is not like Haskell, but its like Python.